# maximum heap size of a running linux process

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks, x86-64

What is the maximum heap size allowed for a running process in a linux system? I am running a x86_64. How can I found the heap memory that is being used from my process?

Comment: These answers are probably far less interesting than the problem that you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you are right. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is 16TB.  But I agree with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, what are you trying to solve?  That's probably far more interesting.

http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2008-12/msg05978.html

Comment: Sounds more like a memory leak than data corruption.  If you were having a data corruption problem you'd be segfaulting more likely than not.  Have you remembered to free() your malloc()s after you're done with them?

Comment: it is a leak definetely. But how but this might be? Let's say that i don't free 10K of data. Let's say that I don't do it 100 times. Is that enought to lead to problems?

Comment: Well, 10k of data 1000 is a 1MB.  On most modern computers that's not a big deal, on a cell phone it is a big deal, on an embedded system you just crashed it.  It might not necessarily be a problem, but I can't know that.  Can you post code?

Comment: @cateof: valgrind is your friend.